# While trying to run the testcases using testng.xml I'm Not getting option to run as Testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin, testng

TestNG is installed in Eclipse, I'm able to run the individual class as Run as TestNG , While trying to Run the testng.xml with Run as TestNG , The option itself is not showing , Request you to please let me know how to resolve this Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the TestNG.xml file directly, right-click on the project in the project explorer and select Run As then TestNG Test

Comment: Yes that worked but it run the test cases in random order manner. And then i have that doubt when we run from there , does it run all the test cases exist in the project or it run trough testng file. And it would be great help too if i got to know why the Testng option is not coming for testng.xml file

Answer (score 0):

This got Resolved, I was using the wrong tags in my TestNG XML. I was using the first character as Capital letter instead of small latter When I made all the tags correct an option to run as TestNG seems visible to Me
    The below code is working perfectly to run Multiple suites using selenium.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
        <suite name="SuiteA"  > 
        <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                     <test name="TestA1" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>

                     <test name="TestA2" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>



        </suite>

        ************************

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
        <suite name="SuiteB"  > 
        <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                     <test name="TestB1" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>

                     <test name="TestB2" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB2" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>


        </suite>

        ***************************

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
        <suite name="SuiteC"  > 
        <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                     <test name="TestC1" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC1" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>

                     <test name="TestC2" allow-return-values="true">
                             <classes>
                               <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                     <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC2" />
                             </classes>
                     </test>


        </suite>

        ********************************

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
        <suite name="TestNG Dadadriver suite"  > 
        <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                <suite-files>
                       <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
                       <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
                       <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />

                </suite-files>


        </suite>
```